# Segmented control with three segment where one segment is disable

Tags: facebook, react-native

[image]

React native segment control where one segment disable and others are clickable .

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Please ask a proper question otherwise people here will not help you.

Comment: @Nino9612 , you are able to get my question??

Comment: @vikash1307 not really because there is no question :) I can only guess you want to know how to implement a segment view

Comment: @Nino9612, i want to react native segment control where, i have 3 segments, in which two are clickable but one is not or vice-versa. Can we have any library like that.

Comment: @Nino9612, that's why i added a screen shot also. Where you can see, first segment is not clickable other two segments are clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after you explained your question properly maybe you can try this libary out: https://github.com/kirankalyan5/react-native-segmented-control-tab

I think that will allow you to achieve what you want. You can also make segments active and disabled whit this library

Comment: i tried this library before asking this question , it will not full fill my requirement.

Comment: well then you should mention that :) Look for some other library then. There a lot on npm

Comment: i all ready searched and tried a lot then i asked question here.